# Building Multiple URLs using modify_url

Tags: r, httr

I created a page scrape function that scrapes some data.  I want to be able to create a list of URL's so that I can pass along more than 1 argument in the function call in order to build different URL's.  Is there a way to do this using `httr::modify_url`?

My code which creates a single URL is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang
library(httr)

# Arguments for Function
hand = NULL
prp = "P"
month = NULL
year = 2019
pitch_type = "FA"
report_type = "pfx"
lim = 0

url <- httr::modify_url("https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php",
                        query = list(
                          hand = hand,
                          reportType = report_type,
                          prp = prp,
                          month = month,
                          year = year,
                          pitch = pitch_type,
                          ds = "velo",
                          lim = lim
                        ))

# Single Query Result
url
#> [1] "https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php?reportType=pfx&prp=P&year=2019&pitch=FA&ds=velo&lim=0"
```

I was wondering if I could use the `httr::modify_url` query from above and  some combination of `purrr::reduce(paste0)` to create the URL's for additional arguments:

```
# Requested Query
pitch_type = c("FA", "SI")
report_type = c("pfx", "outcome")

# URL Generating Function for User inputs
generate_urls <- function(hand = NULL, report_type = c("pfx", "outcome"), prp = "P", month = NULL, year = NULL, pitch_type = c("FA", "SI"), lim = 0) {
# Not sure of what to put in function for modify_url call
}





# Result 
"https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php?reportType=pfx&prp=P&year=2019&pitch=FA&ds=velo&lim=0"
#> [1] "https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php?reportType=pfx&prp=P&year=2019&pitch=FA&ds=velo&lim=0"
"https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php?reportType=pfx&prp=P&year=2019&pitch=SI&ds=velo&lim=0"
#> [1] "https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php?reportType=pfx&prp=P&year=2019&pitch=SI&ds=velo&lim=0"
"https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php?reportType=outcome&prp=P&year=2019&pitch=FA&ds=velo&lim=0"
#> [1] "https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php?reportType=outcome&prp=P&year=2019&pitch=FA&ds=velo&lim=0"
"https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php?reportType=outcome&prp=P&year=2019&pitch=SI&ds=velo&lim=0"
#> [1] "https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php?reportType=outcome&prp=P&year=2019&pitch=SI&ds=velo&lim=0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using tidyverse function. First, we can define the space of parameter that we want to walk over

```
params <- list(
  hand = NULL,
  prp = "P",
  year = 2019,
  month = NULL,
  pitch_type = c("FA", "SI"),
  report_type = c("pfx", "outcome"),
  lim = 0
)
```

Then we can get all the URLs with

```
library(tidyverse) # tidyr for crossing(); purrr for pmap(), map_chr()
library(httr)  
baseurl <- "https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php"
crossing(!!!params) %>% 
  pmap(list) %>% 
  map_chr( ~modify_url(baseurl, query=.x) )
```

the `crossing()` takes care of getting all possible combinations of parameters. The `pmap(list)` then turns each of the rows of the tibble into their own list (which is what we need to pass to `query=` parameter of `modify_url`. Then finally we call the url generating function for each set of parameters and return a character string.

Comment: Where do I get the query from?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz I'm not sure what you are asking. The above code automatically generates the list that you need to pass to the `query=` arguments of `modify_url`. Did you run the code I provided? Did you get an error or something?

Comment: I got `Error in vapply(x, is_empty, logical(1)) : object '.x' not found `.  My function that wraps this scrape is something like `get_tbl <- function(hand = NULL, report_type = "pfx", prp = "P", month = NULL, year = NULL, pitch_type = NULL, lim = 0)`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure which line would be causing the `vapply` error. What versions of `tidyr`, `httr`, `purrr` and `tidyverse` are you using? Also I'm not sure what your `get_tbl` function is. Your question seemed to just ask to generate the list of URLs. I'm not sure what you are actually running.

Comment: I'm using the most up to date version of all of the packages above.  I'm using the CRAN version of `tidyr`.  This might be a dumb question.  Am I supposed to be passing something into the `query` parameters?  What is the `.x` for?  Is the code you posted above everything I need to get the list of URL's?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz Ahh. I found a typo. When I cleaned the code I accidentally removed a `~`. The `.x` value will be set by the `map_chr` function but It needs to be used with the formula syntax for object creation. This is just a convention the `purrr` function use. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for fixing.  One last question, I updated my initial post above.  I want the urls to fit into a function so that the user can define some of the query parameters each time.  How would I do it that way vs. the way you did which had pre-defined parameters for a few variables?